# Showing +20 near my reputation even though it isn't added

Tags: support, reputation

[image: The image in the question]

I have a `+20` symbol near my reputation of 85. But it isn't added to my reputation. Please clarify what it is.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That indicates the amount of reputation you've gained since you last checked your profile.  Your current rep is 85, but it has recently increased by 20.